# What is my degree if I am still a bachelor student?

Tags: degree, terminology

I am registering to submit an article and I am asked to give my current degree, the problem is that I don't have a bachelor degree yet. So, what is the usual term and acronym to use for the current degree if you are still a degree student?

Comment: Leave blank, if possible. Otherwise write something like n/a.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the US system, I would advise to leave it blank. But in some European education systems (and in particular with the impetus of the [Bologna process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bologna_process)), the high-school diploma is considered a formal degree. In France, it is called *baccalauréat*, in the UK it's the A levels, in Spain (you seem to be Spanish) it's the *bachillerato*.

So, if you are in a European system, I would advise you to write *bachillerato*/*baccalauréat*/A-levels, otherwise leave blank.

Comment: In Finland: ylioppilas/student/graduate, depending on which language you want to write it in.